# How to clear a highlighted window in taskbar?

Tags: ubuntu-mate

In case a new window opens when you are working in an other window, the new window isn't brought to the front but is highlighted in the taskbar. The icon is shown in all work-spaces taskbar.

How do I clear this icon to become a normal one from the command line and not bring focus to this new window? (Using the graphical interface I use the mouse pointer and click on it.)

[image: Highlighted sticky windows icon]